# How to learn home improvement for young adults?

Tags: planning, new-home, renovation

I am 22, living with my parents. I plan to buy a house in the next 4 or 5 years. I want to learn more about home improvement so I can renovate my future house easily. My dad does renovations, but I see how his lack of education in this domain makes him do mistakes occasionaly. I want to learn about this domain in case I need to renovate a part of my house or if I need to hire a contractor and make sure he is qualified.

What can I do to learn about home improvement? Read books?

Comment: See [this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53/what-are-the-tools-that-every-do-it-yourselfer-must-own/2052) question and [this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/how-can-i-learn-the-basics-of-home-improvement-projects/11189) question

Comment: Join your local "Habitat for Humanity", depending on the tasks at hand, you may be doing renovations or new home builds. In our group, we had a few professionals volunteering and they were pretty willing to teach to people wanting to learn.